# How to get query details based on results of a query using SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that checks a database for multiple customer barcode scans in a single day.  This report works great, however I'd like to add another piece to it.  I would like to include a column "Times Scanned" to the output.  However, since i'm using "SUM" it won't list multiple times on 1 line.  For example if barcode "1234" is found to be scanned twice, I want the times it was scanned (tickets.dtcreated) to be listed in the "times Scanned" column as one output.

Here is my current Output:

```
Barcode    DtCreatedDate     Number of Scans   
    1234          1/1/2013            2            
    1235          1/1/2013            2            
    1563          1/2/2013            3
```

Here is what I want my output to look like (Keep in mind the "Times Scanned" should only show the times on the day that multiple scans took place (DTcreateddate):

```
Barcode    DtCreatedDate     Number of Scans   Times Scanned
1234          1/1/2013            2            11:15AM, 12:15PM
1235          1/1/2013            2            9:00AM, 4:00PM
1563          1/2/2013            3            8:05AM, 8:08AM, 5:50PM
```

My Current Query is Below

```
 SELECT        Customers.sBarcode, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS dtCreatedDate, COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans]
FROM            Tickets INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE        (Tickets.dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (Tickets.dblTotal <= 0)
GROUP BY Customers.sBarcode, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY dtCreatedDate
```

Comment: What does CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) accomplish?

Comment: This just allows me to pull for a date range.  It was working for a 1 day date range ONLY, until I added this portion.  Now I can run for a date range of whatever I want.

Comment: Why can't you base your date range on tickets.dtCreated?

Comment: User input.  This will be part of a vb.net program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `SUM` for this, but you can use `FOR XML PATH`.  Add this to your SELECT list:

```
SELECT ...,
       STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + RIGHT(convert(varchar, sub.dtCreated, 100), 7)
                    FROM Tickets sub
                    WHERE sub.Ticket_ID = Tickets.Ticket_ID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 2, '' )
       AS [Times Scanned]
FROM Tickets
JOIN ...
```

The idea here is to use `RIGHT(convert(varchar, sub.dtCreated, 100), 7)` to get the formatted time, and then concatenate them using `FOR XML PATH`, while removing the leading comma with `STUFF`

Comment: I'm confused on this.  I get an error on the - I'm guessing right before the select XML.  DO I need to have an XML file somewhere?  OR does it create it on it's own?  It also tells me to declare @startdate...

Comment: @Shmewnix: This is the same query you posted with one extra column inserted - so you'll need a startdate paramter just as in your original query.  And no, you don't need an xml file.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Error in WHERE clause near '-', Error in Where clause near ','  When I run the query I get:
Error source .net sqlclient data provider
error message: must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".
Incorrect syntax near the keywork 'FOR'

Comment: @Shmewnix: Ah, I had a poorly formatted comment in there - fixed

Comment: Updated again to delimit with a comma and space (', ')

Comment: Please look at my edited query.  I had the wrong query listed above.

Comment: @Shmewnix: The actual query doesn't really matter, as long as you filter the subquery on the Tickets.Ticket_ID column as described - I updated my answer to show this more simply.

Comment: Well that's just it.  It should be customer ID, the Ticketsdetails was a table I had on there while trying to figure this out.  I only am referencing 2 tables (Customers and Tickets).

Comment: I made the changes (basically replaced tickets_ID to lCustomerID in both cases.  I get an error "EXPR1 is Too long maximum length is 128

Comment: You can change `RIGHT(convert(varchar, sub.dtCreated, 100), 7)` to `RIGHT(convert(varchar(max), sub.dtCreated, 100), 7)` to fix this.  But I think replacing with lCustomerID is not what you want.  That will cross-join all tickets for that customer instead of for the specific ticket.  You want to match the subquery on something unique to the ticket like Ticket_ID (or whatever the primary key is).

Comment: Hmm, how about `CAST(RIGHT(convert(varchar, sub.dtCreated, 100), 7) as varchar(max))`

Comment: Just to be sure, if you remove this column (that is `STUFF...[Times Scanned])` it works properly?

Comment: Yes.  Without your additions the query runs fine.  The actual error i'm getting is:
Error Source: .net sqlclient data provider
Error Message: the identifier that starts with '[number of scans], Stuff ((Select .... ,7) 'Is too long.  Maximum Length is 128

Comment: This seems to indicate a missing closing bracket or quote - it thinks the query is actually part of the column name you are giving.  Can you check this, or post your complete query?

Comment: I'm seeing `[Number of Scans]]` - the extra `]` bracket is incorrect.

Comment: closer, Does it for ALL dates, not the dates with multiple scans.

Comment: I'm not following you, can you post an example of what is returns and what you expect?

Comment: Well what it's doing is pulling ALL visits by a customer regardless of date.  What I'd like to do is like I post above.  If a customer comes 3 times in one day.  I want to know they were there 3 times, and what times on THAT day they were there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23991/discussion-between-pinnym-and-shmewnix)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing a function to create the list of times called, and then calling that function in your query.

Comment: I do not have the ability to add functions.  The database is synced with a master database once a week, overwriting any changes I make.  the query level is the only way I can accomplish this.

Comment: Can't you get your function added to the master database?

Comment: No, I do not have the ability to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.sBarcode, @startdate AS startdate, @enddate AS enddate, 
       CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS dtCreatedDate, 
       COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans], 
       [Times Scanned] = MAX(STUFF((SELECT ',' + RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, sub.dtCreated, 100), 7)
                                    FROM Tickets AS sub
                                    WHERE sub.Ticket_id = Tickets.Ticket_ID
                                    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))
FROM Tickets INNER JOIN Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE(Tickets.dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (Tickets.dblTotal <= 0)
GROUP BY Customers.sBarcode, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), Tickets.Ticket_ID
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY dtCreatedDate
```

Comment: This actually causes visual studio to crash.

Comment: No Error, it forces the entire program to crash.

Comment: Execute script in Managment Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Oracle (and it's a recent build) you can use the LISTAGG() function

```
LISTAGG(TimesScanned, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TimesScanned)
```

Other DBs sometimes have aggregate functions for this; see this question: [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string/16526394)